# Element-wise apply

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Consider arrays:

```
a = np.array([[nan,  0.,  0.],
              [nan,  1.,  1.],
              [nan,  2.,  nan]])

b = np.array([2., 0., 0.])
```

I'm trying to achieve the following:

- take `x`, which is not missing element in `a`
- replace corresponding item in `b` with `x`
- take sum of that array.

In that case it is:

```
For row = 2, col = 1
a[row, col] -> 2. # 1st col

Replace 1st element in `b` with 2.:
[2., 2., 0.]

Full matrix:
[[nan, sum([2,0,0]), sum([2,0,0])],
 [nan, sum([2,1,0]), sum([2,0,1])],
 [nan, sum([2,2,0]), nan]]

result = [[nan, 2, 2],
          [nan, 3, 3],
          [nan, 4, nan]]
```

How to achieve that `result`?

Comment: Again, how does `0.` become `sum([2,0,0])`?

Comment: @DYZ I'm assuming because summing `b` with the value from `a[0][1]` replacing `b[1]` is `sum([2,0,0])` - the middle `0` gets replaced with a `0`.

Comment: @AChampion Why are there `sum([2,1,0])` and `sum([2,0,1])` in the second row, then, instead of two `sum([2,1,1])`s?

Comment: Just my interpretation - because he wants it element wise, e.g. `a[1][1]` maps to `sum([b[0], a[1][1], b[2]])`, and `a[1][2]` maps to `sum([b[0], b[1], a[1][2]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer is as simple as:

```
a - b + b.sum()
#array([[nan,  2.,  2.],
#       [nan,  3.,  3.],
#       [nan,  4., nan]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
c=np.array([[sum(b.tolist())+y for i in range(len(x))] for y,x in enumerate(a.tolist())])
c[np.isnan(a)]=np.nan
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[ nan   2.   2.]
 [ nan   3.   3.]
 [ nan   4.  nan]]
```

Comment: I want to avoid for loops with numpy

Comment: @koPytok Ok i didn't know so use DYZ's solution